# Pantheon Drupal 7 setup issue with clean url

Tags: drupal-7, pantheon

On my site under admin section node view (node/xxx) is working fine but when I am trying to edit a node (node/xxx/edit) give me following error

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

This issue is only on Pantheon when I do it on my local server it is working fine.

I already checked .htaccess and web.config file. The same configuration is working for me with another setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution. Actually i installed ThemeKey module and the ThemeKey Debug creating redirection issue on Pantheon only i disabled it and site is working.